# proving (inf,min,max)

Tags: calculus

I need to prove for this function:
[image]

that
[image]

and in addition if this function got min/max

i found the derivative but got stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exponential function is always positive so it will add value in total but sin is periodic and minimum value is -1 so if we take limit to exponential to infinity so it goes to zero and take sin some periodic value of -1 so min value of function is -1.